# Rotating a game object to parallel to another objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

i want to rotate axis of X of 'A' like right image.

Here, the rotating degree of A must be parallel to the line connecting the B1 and B2.

How does this script to C#?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to do?

[image]

If yes then it's pretty easy - you set the forward vector of A to the vector from p1 to p2.

```
public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform P1;
    public Transform P2;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.forward = P2.position - P1.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no. instead, using it.

```
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, boundPoint4 - boundPoint3);
        this.TileCollider.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(-1 * rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, rot.w);
```